# What is the difference in these 2 window.location.href redirection? (Chrome)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple page redirection using `window.location.href = ...` in Chrome.

For example, the desired URL is `http://[hostname]:[port]/Error/Timeout`

At first I try use

`window.location.href = window.location.host + "/Error/Timeout"`

Though I logged the URL generated is correct, it does not work, the page does not redirect at all.

Then I changed to

`window.location.href = "/Error/Timeout"`

It works! But the URL generated is exactly the same as previous method.

---

So my question is what makes such difference ?

Comment: in an URL ... `http://somedomain.com/path/file.html` ... host is `somedomain.com`

Comment: "But the URL generated is exactly the same as previous method", it's not.

Comment: check the URL when you do the [window.location.href = window.location.host + "/Error/Timeout"] it adds up the url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `window.location.host` variable contains only the domain (without the protocol), so you are trying to redirect the user to a non-valid URL, and the browser will not allow it.

The "/Error/Timeout" **is** a valid URL, because the browser will look at the "/" at the beginning as "part of the current domain", and just use `PROTOCOL://HOSTNAME:PORT/` combined with the url you provided.

You could also use:

```
window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? (":"+window.location.port):'') + "/Error/Timeout"
```

Or a **much better** option:

```
url = new URL(window.location.href)
url.pathname = "/Error/Timeout"
window.location.href = url.toString()
```

Comment: The latter is the only correct option because you miss the PORT part in the first solution.

Comment: @DannyChen, added the port :)

Comment: Thanks both, especially for the much better option part, really new to me...(though it seems basic)

Comment: Actually it's not so basic. the `URL` API is still considered experimental: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Comment: Because it is experimental, it is only supported in a few browsers. OP specified they're using Chrome so it should be ok, but for IE users, this won't work